# How to enable Play Store auto-update for just a few apps?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

As the title says, I'd like to enable auto-update for trusted apps (e.g. Google apps), but if I open the app in Play Store and check `Auto-update`, I get the question "Auto-update is currently disabled for all apps. Do you want to enable it? You can always change this in Settings. Data charges may apply." Now, if I select Yes, auto-update is turned on for all apps and I have to deselect each one separately.

What I'm looking for is a way to enable auto-update, deselect all apps from auto-update and manually select which apps are allowed to auto-update (i.e. opt-in instead of opt-out).

Running stock 4.2.2 on Sony Xperia Z. I haven't rooted the device so solutions without root are preferred.

EDIT: The situation turned even worse. Now, if I have several apps waiting to be upgraded and I select `Update all`, I get a popup for each and every app asking "Auto-update has been disabled for [app], are you sure you want to update?". Seems like we're being driven to enable auto-update for all apps, and I don't like it.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with Titanium Backup Pro's `Market Auto Updates…` feature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer a non-root solution. But good to know in case I root the phone later.

Answer (score 4):

As you might already know...this feature finally comes in-built with Play Store v4.3.10.
See [this.](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/21/psa-as-of-play-store-v4-3-10-you-can-finally-disable-automatic-updates-for-certain-apps-and-update-all-will-honor-these-settings/)

Comment: Nope, you still need to first enable auto-updates for all apps and disable it one by one. This only applies to the Update All button if the store-wide auto-update is enabled.

Comment: But in this case...on clicking Update All, only those apps that have been selected will be updated. This is what you are looking for right?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the option to enable auto-update so that it works in the background, but only for a few apps. The rest I want to update manually (after I check out the changelog and new reviews) either one by one or with the Update All button.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a similar thread, if you don't want to root your phone there's [Play Apps Updater](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smargav.appsupdater.free). I just installed it and it seems to work, although I can't vouch for it other than that.

Comment: This would have been the best answer. Unfortunately, the devs wrote on the Google Play app page: *Please do not download this app. It does not work anymore due to limitation on Android*.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the desired app, touch the 3-dotted menu button and check auto-update for that app.

Comment: I already tried that, and that option tries to enable auto-update for all apps, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: That's the only non-root method you have to enable auto-update and opt-out all the apps that you don't them auto updating by themselves.