# Allow auto-update of only a single app

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

Is it possible to auto-update selectively? For example, if I want to allow an anti-virus app to update, but no others. Can this be done? Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but very time-consuming.

1. Open the Google Play Store, go to Menu -> Settings.
2. Tap on the "Auto-update apps" and select one of the two "Auto-update apps" options to enable it.
3. Go back, then go to "My apps" section, locate the app you want (e.g. anti-virus app that you mentioned) and tap on it once.
4. Now tap the Menu button and the first option should be the "Auto-update."  Ensure the checkmark is present for this app.
5. For all other apps that you have installed, you will need to follow steps 3 and 4, but this time disable the "Auto-update" setting by unchecking it.

Comment: Actually, from a preventative aspect, I would disable all non-wanted apps first, then set the global setting. Otherwise one or more updateable apps could change during the long manual process!

Comment: @wbogacz I don't think you can modify the per-app setting unless the global one is enabled first.

Comment: fair enough, I didn't know the checkbox was restricted that way.

Comment: Actually for steps 4 and 5 there is bulk functionality provided by [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) app (Market Tools > Market Auto Updates). It's available in PRO (paid) version only.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. Now when clicking the _menu_ button nothing happen. I cannot find other ways to achieve the same result. The "auto-update" tick seems to be completely removed.

Comment: It worked for me now; Google Play vers 5.7.10 :)

Comment: @Kamafeather This works for me with `Play Store version 7.9.80`

Comment: @wbogacz I guess you can turn on airplane mode before. (Not tested.)

Answer (score 9):

First turn on auto update in the main settings of the Play store. Then, you will have to manually open each app in the app store, and un-select auto-update. This will be a painful task, especially if you have more than a handful apps.

Tested on Play Store 4.5.10

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Clicking the phone menu button will not open anything. The "auto-update" checkbox is nowhere now.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to root your phone, there's [Play Apps Updater](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smargav.appsupdater.free). I just installed it and it seems to work, although I can't vouch for it other than that.

Also note that this is a duplicate of [How to enable Play Store auto-update for just a few apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50681/how-to-enable-play-store-auto-update-for-just-a-few-apps/)